# Fact table designing for SSAS

Tags: sql, ssas, cube, fact

I'm designing a fact table for SSAS and this is the first time I'm trying my hand at this as this is to be a prototype system just to show what could be done and to show to someone to decide if it what they are after.

I've made up some data and am now trying to create the fact table. The cube will be looking at referrals and what I'm trying to show is the information over time showing the number of referrals that opened in a month, number that closed in a month and the number that were open at any point in the month (i.e. they could have opened in previous month and closed in a future month).

How is it best to design these measure is where I'm stuck. Should it be three fact tables or can I get away with one? If I do three fact tables, I can link on the record number and the open date to get number that opened in a month, I can link on record number and closed date to create number that closed in a month, but the one I have no idea on is to describe when it was open at any point in the month. For this table would I need to create a row for every day for every referral? This seems a bit intensive and so immediately I thought it was wrong.

So the questions are twofold:

1. Can I do the three measures in one table and if so what is the best method for this?
2. What is the best method for the open at any point in the month count?

Any thoughts would be most appreciated as I truely am a beginner at this and all I have to aid me is google as I have a short deadline for this.

Dimensions I have:

> Demographics: Record number; Gender; Ethnicity; Birth date;
>
> Referral: Record number; Open date; End date;
>
> Time: Date; Month; Quarter; Year;

The fact table I initially designed was:

> Data:
>
> Record number; Opened_in_month; Closed_in_month; Open_in_month;

Since creating the cube, I can see that the numbers do not match up to what I put in the test data and so I know that I have messed up the fact table and it's that table I need to re-create.

Comment: A dimension table of dates has proven to be very useful for our data warehouse.

Comment: I have added in a time dimension which covers the period I want and I link that to the dimensions to create my year/quarter/month hierachy. The issue is how do I implement what I want to count.

Answer (score 0):

I have little experience with creating cubes in SSAS but i would probably create a view as something like this

ReferallFacts:

```
Id | IsOpen | DateOpened | OpenedBy | DateClosed | ClosedBy | OpenForMinutes...
```

CalendarDimension:

```
ShortDate | Week | Month | Quarter | Year | FinancialWeek...
```

EmployeeDimension:

```
Id | FirstName | LastName | LineManager | Department...
```

DepartmentDimension:

```
Id | Name | ParentDepartment | Manager | Location...
```

I don't really see a need for more than one fact table in this case as all of what you describe "by month", "by day" is handled by the calendar dimension.

[Here](http://sql-bi-dev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/creating-first-cube-in-ssas-2008.html) is a really nice walkthough, and also [pcteach.me](http://pcteach.me/?s=SSAS) has some good videos on SSAS.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if I can get the walkthrugh on phone as blocked on work pc. It seems that I need to change the table to be something more like: Data: Record Number; Is_open; date_open; date_closed; Does this result in me having one row per record number in the fact table? I take that it calculates everything as follows: If is_open = 0 then doesn't count it, but how does it cope with this in previous months? E.g. in May it was open and June it isn't so the field would change. Do I need one for row for each day for each record number?

Comment: I had a look at the walkthrough thanks, and I can create a cube and deploy it and even bring it into SharePoint, the problem I've encountered is that the fact table is incorrectly designed and is the last issue I have to crack to get this working properly. The issue I have is that the referral can go from being open in April to closed in May and I need to represent its state at each point in time. I.e. if someone wants to know how many were open in April it will show as open, yet once they after the date it closed it will be counted as closed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered an event-based approach, an event being a referral opening or closing?

First of all, you need to determine the granularity level of your fact table. If you need to know the number of open referrals at a specific date and time in a month, then your fact table must be at the lowest granularity (individual referral records):

```
FactReferrals: ( DateId, TimeId, EventId, RecordNumber, ReferralEventValue )
```

Here, `ReferralEventValue` is just an integer value of 1 when a Referral opens, and -1 when a Referral closes. EventId refers to a dimension with only two members: `Opened` and `Closed`.

This approach allows you to get the number of closed or opened events over any given time period. Also, by taking the sum of `ReferralEventValue` from the beginning of time, and up to a certain point in time, you get the exact amount of open referrals at that specific moment. To speed up this sum in SSAS, you could design aggregations or create a separate measure that is the accumulated sum of ReferralEventValue.

Edit: Of course, if you don't need data at individual referral granularity, you could always sum up the ReferralEventValue per day or even month, before loading the fact table.

Comment: So I would need one entry per day the referral was open per record? E.g. DateID,EventID; Record Number; ReferralEventValue;

Comment: Yes, actually you would need two entries per referral. One entry for the date the record was opened, and another for when it was closed. But if you don't need data at individual referral granularity, you could also sum up all opened referrals per day (or week, or month) in one entry, and all closed referrals per day (or week, or month) in another entry.

Comment: Ah ok. I was thinking I would need one for each day the referral was open and not two, one for the open and close dates. I do need referral level at the lowest level but upwards could just be aggregates done in SSAS.